# Application failed to start after spring boot version upgrade from 2.1.18.RELEASE to 2.2.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When we upgrade the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 2.1.8.RELEASE to 2.2.0.RELEASE, the application is not loading few beans. Due to this, application is failing. @PostConstuct is not able to add BCFIPS Provider in security provider.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.yyy.ekms.sdk")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "ekms.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class EKMSClientSdkConfiguration extends ClientConfiguration
{
    @PostConstruct
    public void addSecurityProvider()
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClientBuilder apiClientBuilder()
    {
        return new DefaultApiClientBuilder();
    }
}
```

Also, apiClientBuilder bean is not getting created.

The EKMSClientSdkConfiguration is extending ClientConfiguration, which is coming as part of another application jar. This class is not having any annotation.

```
public abstract class ClientConfiguration {
    public ClientConfiguration() 
    {
    }

    public abstract void addSecurityProvider();

    @Bean
    public EKMSClient restClient() {
        return new EKMSRestClientImpl(this.apiClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient() {
        return Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
    }
}
```

In our case, EKMSClientSdkConfiguration bean is not getting created and the @PostConstruct is also not getting executed.

I went through the [Spring Boot 2.2.RELEASE notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes) which is pointing to [Spring Framework 5.2 upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-52). Here, I learned that spring boot 2.2.0 RELEASE is using Spring framework 5.2. In Spring framework 5.2, we have many changes.

[image]

It looks like this is the root cause of bean not getting loaded, but I am not sure about it.

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: pretty sure abstract classes also need an `@configuration`  when defining beans in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found spring.main.lazy-initialization=true property in my application which was causing the above issue. When I removed it from the application.properties, This issue is resolved. This is the major change which was introduced in 2.2.0.RELEASE of spring boot